# SAXParseException when running Spring 3 JUnit

Tags: spring, junit, xml-validation

I just upgraded to Spring 3, and attempted to run some JUnits to make sure everything was copacetic. It wasn't. I got a `SAXParseException` when loading the context... it complained:

> Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

My suspicion is that it couldn't access the XSD due to proxy configuration. Is there a way to make it stop trying so hard to validate it and just run the darn thing? :)

In all seriousness, though, I didn't have a problem when I was running under Spring 2, so I suspect that Spring 2 didn't bother to try to validate, but Spring 3 does. I was hoping there was a way to bypass that functionality.

One further clue... Since I couldn't run the JUnits, I went ahead and fired up the server (this is a web app), and everything seemed to go swimmingly. So that makes me think that Spring is just fine with my context files as they are.

**Edit** The same error occurs when using instead the Spring 3.0 schemas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my problem was a result of re-bundling the spring jars into a single jar. Just using the separate jars worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are using xsd of spring 2.  You could try using `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd`.